# Problem / Question with VUE Frontend and PHP Backend / Api

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, session, jwt

First of all sorry for my english, since its not my native language. Hope its clear enough.

We are developing a user system where the user, after login in, can do various things like joining events, changing his profile data, leave messages in a board so others users can read and answer to it, etc.
The idea is to have two different "projects", one for the backend ( already almost done as a CRUD Api using PHP ) and the frontend with VUE JS.

Both projects will be hosted on the same server so once its deployed we wont have any CORS or related problems.

At the moment the backend uses PHP Session ( could spend time changing the auth system if realy needed ) to know the user is loged in. Been testing with postman and everything seems to work as intended.

My problem comes on how to handle user sessions, to know the user is loged in etc during the development. Once the project is done and deployed on the same server, there would be no problem on using PHP Session or using JWT / Cookies. But during development, ***I see no way of testing the frontend without building it before because the API will be either on the server deployed already or localy on xampp***, both ways giving me a lot of troubles because:

**PHP SESSION:**
As the php session is domain exclusive, each request from the frontend to the backend, as long as they are not on the same server, will be taken as different sessions.

**JWT:**
JWT Could be a solution but only if storing the token on localstorage, sessionstorage or a cookie that is not httponly because if i want the backend to set a httponly cookie with the token that cookie wont be available while in development because of different servers, not letting me test the frontend properly without building it and either deploying it to the host or copying it to xampp.
About localstorage, sessionstorage or normal cookies, after reading a lot, i discarded them because of the security problems it can cause like XSS, CSRF, etc.

So summarizing, I would say the best idea would be to use the php session as both projects will be hosted together but I have no idea how I can test the frontend without having to build it and uploading it or moving the dist folder to xampp.

Thanks for your time and hope you can enlighten me

Comment: i ran into this problem before. you can ( during development ) set response headers from PHP ```Access-Control-Allow-Origin``` to whatever origin you are using and ```Access-Control-Allow-Credentials``` to true. that would share session across origins

Comment: Thanks for your time Talal. I have tried this before and if im not wrong this would only solve CORS problems while doing a request, but It wont solve my problem with the php session because session wont be saved and also it wont solve the problem of creating an httponly cookie right?. Thanks

Comment: actually it is working right now. i made couple of projects using nuxt which is basically vue and PHP provides session only log in. if i close the browser i have to log in again which is perfect for the project. it works when developing using localhost:3000 and works when using localhost and to be more specific i use Phalcon. im happy to share code if you like

Comment: i forgot to add that ```Access-Control-Allow-Credentials``` works in conjunction with ```XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials``` which i use ```axios``` for that and it works fine

Comment: Thanks again. Tried it with a simple example  and nothing. The example was as follow.     this.axios.get(URL, {withCredentials: true }).then( function(response){
      console.log(response);
    })
On the php i have both headers, origin, and credentials and i check if the session exist and if not i create it and assing a string to a session variable to then try if it keeps it. But on the second request the session will appear as empty. I can see on the response headers "set-cookie: PHPSESSID=9hs288a933je6umklan0eldrtv; path=/" but the next time the PHPSESSID is different.

Comment: Before I would have said that behaviour is the normal and the expected, php session working only on the same domain, but since you said that, idk. Tomorrow i will keep trying. Thanks

Comment: sure why not. i'm going to write it in plain php and create a gist for it

Comment: That would be nice. Gonna keep trying meanwhile tho. Thanks

Comment: I've find out that if set the session cookie to
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', "1"); 
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', "1"); 
ini_set('session.cookie_samesite','None');
while using the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials as you said, i will get the session cookie.
Now, i dont know if this is somehow more insecure than what php sessions are normaly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the php response headers to allow credentials as [Talal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2640796/talal) suggested on the comments:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
```

On the axios call passing the param withcredentials: true

```
this.axios.get(URL, {withCredentials: true })
```

Would solve most of the CORS problems, the server would send the session cookie on the response, but still the browser would refuse to save the cookie because of the SameSite beeing unset (Chrome sets it to Lax as default ).
Solved this with:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', "1"); 
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', "1"); 
ini_set('session.cookie_samesite','None');
```

Comment: did the session persist ?

Comment: Setting the cookie / session as secure and samesite as none yes it did. I guess having setting those only while on development will do the trick. Thanks Talal